# Open .sdf file in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2022

I have a `.sdf` file (265 MB), and I need to open it with Visual Studio 2022. I have downloaded 'SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox'. Then I added connection and chose 'SQL Server Compact 4.0 (by Simple ErikEJ).

When I clicked on 'test', it displayed:

> Test connection succeeded

But when I clicked on 'OK', it displayed:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data provider. It may not be installed

I have searched some solutions about it. I tried to modify 'machine.config' file, but it didn't work.

Also I downloaded and installed 'SSCERuntime-ENU.exe', it didn't work,too.
So how to open `.sdf` file in Visual Studio?

---

Updated: I opened 'SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox', then click 'Add SQL server compact connection'. When I tested connection, it displayed the error below.

[image: this error].

Comment: You can easily add a connection to it in the Toolbox. So what do you mean by "open" exactly?

Comment: Considering that SQL Server CE was deprecated in 2013, and support ended in 2021, perhaps you would be better off using a different back end database? Have you considered LocalDB or (SQL Server) Express?

Comment: @Larnu Thak you! I have tried to open with LINQPad7. But it noted that 'the database file may be corrupted. Run the repair utility to check the database file'.

Comment: My point is that perhaps you should be considering using a completely different database product (or edition of SQL Server) to *start* with. *Old* versions of SSMS (looks like SSMS 2008 was the last version) support opening a Compact Edition database, so you might find that downloading one of those (that still supported CE), connecting to the file and scripting out what you need and then migrating to a different product (like Express/LocalDB) would be the better option. If you already have the definitions, I would suggest just creating the new database and not worry about the CE one.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your suggestion. I would try this later, if I can't find a good solution in Visual studio.

Comment: @ErikEJ Thank you very much. I found the toolbox, but an exception still occurred. It said my file may be corrupted. I have updated my question. My database is downloaded from https://lipidmaps.org/data/structure/download.php. So I think there is no corruption in data. Hoping to get your help. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you very much. It's true. I have just opened it with 'DataWarrior', a cheminformatics tool, according to your answer.

Comment: @ErikEJ I have found the solution. This is not a SQL Server Compact Database problem. Sorry to interrupt you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is a chemical structure-data file. Although the extension is .sdf, it is different from SQL Server Comapct Database file. Many chemical structure software can open it, like DataWarrior.